# Dynamic queryset based on current user

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, django-queryset

I have two models: `UserEdus` and `Question`.

I need to get all `Questions` that have a specific `UserEdus` as their author.

Models.py

```
class UserEdus(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

class Question(models.Model):
author = models.ForeignKey(UserEdus, null=False)
```

Views.py

```
class MyQuestionListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Question
    paginate_by = 10
    queryset = Question.objects.filter(author=User.useredus)
    template_name = 'edus/myquestion_list.html'
```

This queryset returns `int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'ReverseOneToOneDescriptor'`

If I do

```
queryset = User.useredus.question.all()
```

that returns `'ReverseOneToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'question'`

Although on the template level, I can get the correct result using

```
{% for question in user.useredus.question_set.all %}
```

Comment: You're sure you don't want author=UserEdus instead? Given the Question model, that's about the only thing the author field can be: it has an FK to UserEdus.

Comment: try `(author=request.user)` instead of `(author=User.useredus)`

Comment: @Evert, doing that returns the same int()argument error
hansTheFranz, that returns request is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're going to have to override the `get_queryset` method if you want to dynamically set the queryset based on the request user. So do something like this:

```
class MyQuestionListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Question
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name = 'edus/myquestion_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.request.user.useredus.question_set.all()
```